# Does anyone know what this notation means?

Tags: notation

Deﬁne $Z = N \times N$. For We wish to deﬁne a binary structure $+:Z \times Z \to Z$ by: For $x, y \in Z$ choose $(a, b) \in x$ and $(\alpha, \beta) \in y$ then deﬁne $x + y = \overline{(a + \alpha, b + \beta)}$.

The "(a + α,b + β)" has a bar over it. What does that mean? I remember the complex conjugate having a bar over it, but never like this. Anyone know?

Comment: In what context does this appear?

Comment: Abstract algebra.

Comment: More specifically...

Comment: I mean what is being defined? For what purpose is the book making this definition. An overline can mean many different things in "abstract algebra", from reduction modulo a prime to complex conjugation to Galois closure

Comment: Well, I'm at the beginning of the course. The homeworks are based around isomorphisms, equivalence relations, binary structures and things of that nature

Comment: I think that you’ve omitted something from the definition of $Z$. Are you sure that $Z$ isn’t a set of **equivalence classes** of elements of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, rather than $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ itself?

Comment: And did they really use the same plus sign everywhere?

Comment: It's not the book making the definition, it's my professor.

Comment: What came immediately before? What comes immediately after. It's impossible to work it out just from this snippet.

Comment: I copied it verbatim. The only thing I couldn't copy was the bar at the top of the ordered pair

Comment: @GitGud Isn't that common? For instance $(f+g)(x) \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} f(x) + g(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, everything was put exactly as is. Has anyone seen that bar notation in areas besides conjugates of complex numbers?

Comment: It can’t be right. In order to choose an element of $x$ when $x\in Z$, $x$ must be a set, but if $Z$ is $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, its elements aren’t sets (in this context).

Comment: @user121615: It’s used for **many** things. Here it almost certainly means the equivalence class of the object under it with respect to some previously defined equivalence relation. Unfortunately, we don’t know what that relation is. Either you’ve not recognized that something else is part of the context here, or your instructor made a mistake.

Comment: @GPerez If it's an analyst writing, yeah, it's common. Otherwise, while introducing definitions, authors usually explicitly explain what's going on. Eventually the heavy notations are abandoned in favor of more practical ones.

Comment: Well, this is all one problem. The problem doesn't say that I should use the results of any previous question. But the previous question is this : Let ∼ be the relation on N×N, given by (a,b) ∼ (a',b') if a + b' = a' + b. Prove ∼ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: @GitGud Oh, alright then, thanks.

Comment: After staring at this for a bit, my best guess is that it’s supposed to be part of a construction of the integers from the natural numbers. We first define $Z=\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. We then define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $Z$ by $\langle k,\ell\rangle\sim\langle m,n\rangle$ iff $k+n=\ell+m$ and write $\overline{\langle m,n\rangle}$ for the $\sim$-class of $\langle m,n\rangle$. The exercise itself is then defining the addition operation on $Z/\!\!\sim$. Ha! And now I see from @user121615’s last comment that this is in fact the case: the previous exercise set the stage for this one.

Comment: @user121615 That would probably be your $Z$ then, namely $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N /\sim$